# Android is there a way to style all widget?

Tags: android, android-studio

hi guys I'm new to styling android layouts and I want to ask if there is a way to apply a drawable background to a widget (ex: all buttons in a layout) without having to type the android:drawable in each widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it in every layout but you can also add it programmatically by iterating every control on the page.  I did this recently.  I didn't like the result because it was impossible (literally) to check the existing styling to see if I needed to replace it -I didn't want to restyle labels- but it was something like this:

```
//change linerlayout to whatever viewgroup type you have
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.name_of_your_linearlayout);
for(int count = 0; count < layout.getChildCount(); count ++) {
    if (layout.getChildAt(count)) instanceOf EditText) {
       /*do your work here.  Note you don't have to limit yourself
         to theming.  You could add an event to every button or textbox
         at the same time */
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this method better. Thank you ^-^

Answer (score 1):

You can create class extend Button :

```
public class CustomButton extends Button {

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        //set drawable here
    }

}
```

and in xml file call CustomButton :

```
        <yourpackage.name.CustomButton 
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:text="CustomButton" />
```